# Need to build a logic for random selection of product in PLP

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I'm new to selenium automation testing I built a logic for the site automation but in this logic, I manually picked one product. Did the testing for it now I need to build a logic for random selection of the product from PLP and it adds to the cart.

I used
jp@gc - WebdDriverSampler for logic

CSV Data set the config for dynamic input

script language -javascript

Thanks in advance.

PLP:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9H1M.jpg)

```
WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//*[@id='mm-0']/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/input")).sendKeys(CapCodeInput);//this line for dynamic value input
WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//div[@id='mm-0']/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/button")).click();// submit 

WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//*[@id='mm-0']/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/button")).click();// Allproducts button 
WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//*[@id='mm-0']/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/header/div[2]/div/nav/ul/li[1]/a")).click();//PLP

WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//div[@id='mm-0']/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div[5]/div/a/img")).click();//This is single product xpath

var wait = new pkg.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, java.time.Duration.ofSeconds(15))
var conditions = org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions
wait.until(conditions.elementToBeClickable(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath('//*[@id="customizer-container"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/button'))).click();




var start = new Date().getTime()
var attempt = 1
while (new Date().getTime() - start < 5000) {
    try {
        var button = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.xpath("//*[@id='mm-0']/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[10]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/a/span"))
        button.click();
        WDS.log.info('Element found')
        break
    }
    catch (err) {
        WDS.log.info('Attempt # ' + attempt + ', Element not found)
        java.lang.Thread.sleep(1000)
        attempt++
    }
}
```

The above logic is for a single product and I need help to build logic for a random selection of products the image is attached for reference.

Looked for references, but did not find the exact solution to the problem. Need the logic for the random selection of products and add it to the cart.

Comment: Have you tried something like this? Get all the product elements (by class, for example, or any other selector) with `document.querySelectorAll(<your_selector>)`, create a random number between 0 and `elem.array.length-1`, simulate clicking on it (if that's how you add it to cart).

Comment: [Please do not upload screenshots of code](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  Post the actual code instead and use code markdown.